# Edit php.ini File in CPanel Not Found

Tags: php, cpanel

My site was developed using WordPress installation.

I've retrieved the CPanel info from the Host.
I want to access the php.ini (settings) file but it is not there on CPanel.
I've checked through all the categories on the CPanel Home starting from (Files, Databases, SEO, and Marketing Tools, Domains, Email, Metrics, Security, Software, Advanced, Preferences, Softaculous Installer etc.) and nothing like PHP configuration or Edit PHP Settings etc.

I've called my Host and he seems to be angry that I want to design my site by myself. From what he said, the php.ini file is under Perl Repository.
But there is nothing like that on the CPanel.

The php.ini is not even residing under the public_html directory.

Comment: Only your host provider can give you exact location of `php.ini` file on the server.

Comment: YOU CAN CREATE YOUR OWN `php.ini` and upload it to the hosting root.

Comment: If I decide to create my own, let's say, I copy the Wamp Server's settings. What's the disadvantage by doing this? However, I tried to send mail using Mail() on my script. But the script returned no error, and the mail was not sent. I need to check whether the problem is with the php.ini file.

Comment: Why your host is angry to you for you are designing your webpage yourself. They should be happy because of sold you a host.

Comment: @eyo usually, cpanel installation put error_log for php issues of user, on same directory where script resides. Try search error_log. If not, you can define more debug on Wordpress https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Answer (score 1):

- php.ini under CPanel server are at /usr/local/lib/php.ini
- Normal user (not root) can't edit this file
- Under some circunstances, it's possible create a php.ini Personalized.

  - Apache + PHP it's not on mode DSO PHP (usually most hosters has this wrong mode)
  - The Sysadmin has not overrride the possibility that the user use a php, ini custom
- The most important. If your hoster replied what has replied, I would think very seriously change company.

Comment: Why I needed the php.ini file was to check the mail(), because I tried using it to send but the mail did not deliver. However, I figured that the Host had disabled the mail() function for security reasons. So, I decided to use php mailer class to bypass the disabled mail() function and it worked. I really appreciate all your efforts. You guys are real brothers out there. Thank you all. God bless you.

Comment: @Eyo i'f like with answers, please Vote answers those who helped him. This also improves the site. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers